# Adding in component from third party on beta version of angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have a large project in angular 2 rc3 .. can't afford to update it to the latest.

I'm following instructions to add third party components like this one:

https://github.com/gmostert/ng2-breadcrumb

I do my best considering my syntax is different from the latest angular 2 but I get errors

```
import {Ng2BreadcrumbModule, BreadcrumbService} from 'ng2-breadcrumb/ng2-breadcrumb';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [BreadcrumbService]  
})
```

error:

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/ng2-breadcrumb/ng2-breadcrumb 404 (Not Found)
```

Doesn't look like it's looking for this thing in the node_modules folder?  I think I have to handle this in system-config.ts or something?

Please advise.. I spend way too much time trying to figure out how to get these dependencies working properly..

```
// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  '@ngrx': 'vendor/@ngrx',
  'file-saver': 'vendor/file-saver',
  'ng2-breadcrumb': 'npm:ng2-breadcrumb'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  '@ngrx/core': {
     main: 'index.js',
     format: 'cjs'
   },
   '@ngrx/store': {
      main: 'index.js',
      format: 'cjs'
    },
   'ng2-breadcrumb': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },    
    'file-saver': {
      main: 'fileSaver.js',
      format: 'cjs'
    }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',
  'file-saver',
  'xlsx',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/admin-dashboard',
  'app/products',
  'app/users',
  'app/login',
  'app/clients',
  'app/reducers',
  'app/actions',
  'app/table',
  'app/users-list',
  'app/search',
  'app/form',
  'app/forgot-password',
  'app/product-data',
  'app/client-edit',
  'app/user-edit',
  'app/client-dashboard',
  'app/scrub-dashboard',
  'app/components/scrub/dashboard',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-dashboard',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-editorial',
  'app/components/form/dropdown',
  'app/components/table/editorial-report-table',
  'app/components/table/editorial-report-table/editorial-report-table',
  'app/components/table/abstract-table/abstract-table',
  'app/components/table/abstract-table',
  'app/tables',
  'app/components/table',
  'app/components/tables/editorial-report-table',
  'app/components/cells/editorial-report-cell',
  'app/components/table-rows/editorial-report-row',
  'app/services/api/api-service',
  'app/components/form/scrub-search',
  'app/components/table-header',
  'app/components/table-footer',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-products-review',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-product-review',
  'app/components/table-rows/product-review-report-row',
  'app/modal',
  'app/components/modal',
  'app/components/product/top10-reviews',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-product-faq',
  'app/components/table-rows/product-faq-report-row',
  'app/components/product/questions',
  'app/recent-reviews',
  'app/components/product/recent-reviews',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-pricing-inventory',
  'app/components/table-rows/pricing-inventory-report-row',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-search-result',
  'app/components/table-rows/search-result-report-row',
  'app/components/form/file-upload-input',
  'app/components/form/retailer-dropdown',
  'app/components/form/client-dropdown',
  'app/components/form/report-type-dropdown',
  'app/components/form/frequency-dropdown',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-automated-report',
  'app/components/product/update-from',
  'app/components/form/file-upload',
  'app/components/table-rows/scrub-automated-reporting',
  'app/components/table-rows/automated-reporting-row',
  'app/components/product/automated-report',
  'app/components/scrub/scrub-price-comparison',
  'app/components/form/comparison-search',
  'app/components/table-rows/price-comparison-row',
  'app/edit-profile',
  'app/breadcrumb',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js',
    '@ng2-breadcrumb': 'ng2-breadcrumb.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to add to the `systemjs.config` file. You should have the following

```
map: {
  'ng2-breadcrumb': 'npm:ng2-breadcrumb'
},
packages: {
  'ng2-breadcrumb': {
     defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

You will also need to declare the `BreadcrumbComponent` in order to be able to use the `breadcrumb` element

```
import {BreadcrumbComponent, BreadcrumbService} from 'ng2-breadcrumb/ng2-breadcrumb';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  directives: [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,
    BreadcrumComponent
  ],
  providers: [BreadcrumbService]  
})
```

You won't need the `Ng2BreadcrumbModule`, as that is only for RC6 and later.

If the systemjs mapping doesn't work, please update your post with the config file. You may have different structuring of the mappings, so it may not be so obvious how to go about adjusting it

Comment: getting this error: zone.js:101 XMLHttpRequest cannot load npm:ng2-breadcrumb/ng2-breadcrumb.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

ill post my system js file above

Comment: I guess you should change it to vendor `'ng2-breadcrumb': 'vendor/ng2-breadcrumb'`. I'm not sure where the `vendor` is coming from, but it looks like the other libraries are using that also